# Apache 2.x auth before mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, authentication, mod-rewrite, ldap

I have an apache server that was initially set up for intranet access, so I didn't have to worry much about locking it down.

Later on, I needed to open it up to the internet, so I put an ldap authentication directive in the  section of the httpd.conf like so:

```
 Order allow,deny

 AuthBasicProvider ldap
 AuthType Basic
 AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
 AuthName "MyCompany Intranet"
 AuthLDAPURL "ldap://myldapserver.mydomain.com:389/CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(memberOf=CN=Everyone at MyCompany,OU=MyCompany Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=com)" NONE
 AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
 AuthLDAPBindPassword "MyPassword"

 Require valid-user

 #Allow from all
 Allow from 192.168.1
 Allow from 10.254.0

 Satisfy any
```

This basically made it so that local users could get in with no password, and external users had to authenticate against our ADS domain to get in.

Now things get more complicated.

I have an app that I run that distinguishes between users by appending a cgi variable to the end of a URL, so I setup a .htaccess file in the root of my web directories (/var/www/html) as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ some/really/long/url/$1?tenant_filter=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$ some/really/long/url/$1?tenant_filter=1 [L]
```

This works really great.  Clients type in http://myserver.mydomain.com/foo/file.html and the URL magically points them at http://myserver.mydomain.com/some/really/long/url/file.html?tenant_filter=2 while all they see is the http://myserver.mydomain.com/foo/file.html.

Here's where the problem comes in.

I'd like to define *separate* authentication parameters for the /foo and /bar virtual directories.  No matter what I try, the authentication is always overridden by the ldap setup in my http.conf above.  What am I doing wrong and what can I do to achieve my goal?  Is it even possible?

Comment: in what context of the config file are you adding this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem was to create target directories in /var/www/html called foo and bar.  Authentication was then setup for the directories in the /etc/httpd/conf.d directories as below:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/bar">    
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Bar Extranet"
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://myldapserver.mydomain.com:3268/DC=mydomain,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on

    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "mypassword"

    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on

    require ldap-group CN=Bar Kiosk,OU=mycompany Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=com

    Allow from 192.168.1
    Allow from 10.254.0

    Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

The target directory of the rewrites was set to accept authentication from either foo or bar as below:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/some/really/long/directoryname>
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "mycompany Extranet"
   AuthLDAPURL ldap://myldaphost.mydomain.com:3268/DC=mydomain,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
   AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on

   AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword "mypassword"

   AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on

   require ldap-group CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com
   require ldap-group CN=BAR Kiosk,OU=mycompany Groups,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com

   Allow from 192.168.1
   Allow from 10.254.0

   satisfy any
</Directory>
```

Although this allows both foo and bar to access the target directory, it is sufficient for my needs, as the target directory is obfuscated by the URL rewrite code.

I also changed the code in the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file for the URL rewrites to prevent loops:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)tenant_filter=1$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)tenant_filter=2$
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ some/really/long/url/$1?tenant_filter=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$ some/really/long/url/$1?tenant_filter=1 [L]
```

Lastly, my situation was complicated by the fact that I am running BlueDragon 7.1 for Linux on that server.  I did not mention it in my initial post, but BD was not recognizing some of the changes I was making in my Apache configs without being restarted.  This greatly complicated the process.

Answer (score 0):

Authorization configuration options can be placed in <Location> and <Directory> sections. However:

> [...] <Location> directives should not be used to control access to filesystem locations. Since several different URLs may map to the same filesystem location, such access controls may by circumvented.

That doesn't seem to be a problem in your case, since that looks to be exactly the behavior you're looking for.